# マクロで１行おきに2行セルを挿入したいがうまく動きません

Tags: vba, excel

1行おきに2行空白のセルを挿入したいのですが、下記のマクロでは1行おきに1行しか挿入できません。他の列はそのままで、C列のみ、そのような処理をしたいと思っております。

恐らく、ここが違うのだと思いますが、

```
ActiveCell.Offset(行数, 0).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

自力では解決できず。ご教示いただけますと幸いです！

**現状のコード**

```
Sub 一行おきに一行セルを挿入()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    行数 = 1
    Range("C2").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(行数).Value <> ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(行数, 0).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ActiveCell.Offset(行数).Select
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 恐らく、ここが違うのだと思いますが、
>
> ```
> ActiveCell.Offset(行数, 0).Select
> ```

はい。
`Offset`はActiveCellからの相対位置を示すだけで、選択範囲は1セルのみです。
複数行を挿入する場合は、`Resize`や`Range`を使用して複数行を選択した後に挿入処理を行ってください。

下記のコードは`Offset`と`Resize`を併用して目的の動作を実現するサンプルです。

```
Sub 一行おきに二行セルを挿入()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    行数 = 1
    Range("C2").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(行数).Value <> "" 
        ActiveCell.Offset(行数, 0).Resize(2).Select '1行下のオフセットを起点として、選択範囲を2行分にリサイズして選択
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ActiveCell.Offset(2).Select 'アクティブセルを2行下に移動
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**参考資料**

- [Offset、Resizeを使いこなそう](https://excel-ubara.com/excelvba4/EXCEL210.html)

Comment: payanecoさん　有難うございます！とても勉強になります。取り急ぎ、ご提供いただいたコードにて、動作確認してバッチリでした！　自分でも勉強して、コード作成できるよう精進いたします。